# error after updating the database

Tags: java, methods

I have this method that updates the rows from the database.

```
private void setLabels() {
    int rows = connect.countRows();
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        Object labelObj = table.getModel().getValueAt(i, 3);
        Object idObj = table.getModel().getValueAt(i, 0);
            int idu = (Integer) idObj; 
            String label = (String) labelObj; 
            connect.updateDataLabels(label, idu);
            System.out.println("Add " + i);
    }
}
```

**everything works fine but I don't understand why I got the OutOfBounds error:**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
    at javax.swing.JTable$1.getValueAt(JTable.java:690) 
    at javax.swing.JTable$1.getValueAt(JTable.java:690)
    at LabelMessages.setLabels(LabelMessages.java:79)
    at LabelMessages.actionPerformed(LabelMessages.java:71)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
etc.
```

Comment: Have u tried debugging your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might indicate that your connect.countRows() returns the value 10 while your table model has only 9 of them. How about using table.getModel().getRowCount() instead of connect.countRows()?